# How can I enable syntax colouring in vim using Terminal?

Tags: terminal

I am new to mac

I want to change the look of my Terminal.app window so that it look like Ubuntu's terminal

[image: Terminal of mac]

[image: Ubuntu Terminal]

How can I configure my Mac terminal so that code in vim look colourful? 
I.e. such that data type, special functions, header files have a different colour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `:syntax on` inside vim or add `syntax on` to your .vimrc.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to consider iTerm 2 as well - it's a great terminal emulator and it will let you go full screen and will let you have a greater number of colors.